# Tracking on woocommerce site

Tags: woocommerce, parameters, event-tracking

I have a 3rd party CRM system for mailing, and want to set up product interest and abandoned cart flows.

For this i have inserted a tracking code on the site, and then in the guide to the setup it just says to instert a visit event on product pages for product interest and it should look like this:
hlt.visit(PRODUCTID, CATEGORYID, CATEGORYNAME);
where PRODUCTID, CATEGORYID and CATEGORYNAME should be replaced with the params used on the site.

I have no idea how to find out which parameter my site uses for e.g productid.

How do i figure this out?

The script looks something like this for the product page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 var hlt;
 var BiTrackingLoaded = function (BiTracking) {
 hlt=BiTracking;
 BiTracking.initialize('INSERTAPIKEYHERE', INSERTSESSIONTIMEHERE);
 hlt.visit(“PRODUCTID”,”CATEGORYID”,"CATEGORYNAME") }
</script>
<script>
 (function (d, t) {
 var g = d.createElement(t),
 s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
 h = "https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://";
 g.src = h + 'tracking.heycommerce.dk/hlbi.js';
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
 }
 (document, 'script'));
</script>
```

Comment: Is this script added only on the product page?
Are you using a plugin to add the script? Or are you using PHP via the wp_head hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the product interest try the following:

Add the script via your child theme functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'zz_add_tracking_codes');
function zz_add_tracking_codes(){
    // adding on product page only
    if(is_singular( 'product' )){
        $produc_id = get_the_id();
        // Remember a product can have multiple categories so if you can only add one you get the frist element form array.
        $categories = get_the_terms( $produc_id, 'product_cat');
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        const PRODUCTID = '<?php echo $produc_id; ?>';
        const CATEGORYID = '<?php echo $categories[0]->term_id; ?>';
        const CATEGORYNAME = '<?php echo $categories[0]->name; ?>';
        var hlt;
        var BiTrackingLoaded = function (BiTracking) {
        hlt=BiTracking;
        BiTracking.initialize('INSERTAPIKEYHERE', INSERTSESSIONTIMEHERE);
        hlt.visit(PRODUCTID,CATEGORYID,CATEGORYNAME) }
        </script>
        <script>
        (function (d, t) {
        var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        h = "https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://";
        g.src = h + 'tracking.heycommerce.dk/hlbi.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
        }
        (document, 'script'));
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like it does the trick perfectly.

If i want to use it on the cart page for abandoned cart, and need to fire it from all the products there, i can use this code too somehow right? by making a foreach loop over items in the cart?

Comment: @TobiasNørbygaard for the abandoned cart you’ll have to use a different approach. Currently you are sending data on page visit, but for the abandoned cart you need a way of checking if that cart was really abandoned and I don’t think it should be on Cart page load.

Comment: Angel Marinez Actually the event from the CRM system is an add to basket event, and then using the items from the cart page that has been added to the basket it can check and see if those items also gets bought within X amount of time and if not send a mail out. So it should just send data on page load

Comment: @TobiasNørbygaard do you mean you have to also handle sending data on [added to cart] and then on every cart page load? You will need to share more info about the CRM API.

Comment: https://support.heyloyalty.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020072411-9-2-Dokumentation-Heycommerce-produkt-tracking

This is what i have of documentation from the CRM, i just need to send the data on cart load, and as minimum product id and amount